# Using Java reflection to create eval() method

Tags: java, reflection

I have a question about reflection
I am trying to have some kind of eval() method. So i can call for example:

```
eval("test('woohoo')");
```

Now I understand the there is no eval method in java but there is reflection. I made the following code:

```
String s = "test";
Class cl = Class.forName("Main");
Method method = cl.getMethod(s, String.class);
method.invoke(null, "woohoo");
```

This works perfectly (of course there is a try, catch block around this code). It runs the test method. However I want to call multiple methods who all have different parameters.

I don't know what parameters these are (so not only String.class). But how is this possible? how 
can I get the parameter types of a method ?
I know of the following method:

```
Class[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
```

But that will return the parameterTypes of the method I just selected! with the following statement:

```
Method method = cl.getMethod(s, String.class);
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: The eval method looks like Ruby's eval, so maybe you could look at how [JRuby](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/sources) does it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to call [`Class.getMethods()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()) and iterate through them looking for the correct function.

```
For (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
  if (method.getName().equals("...")) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The reason for this is that there can be multiple methods with the same name and different parameter types (ie the method name is overloaded).

`getMethods()` returns all the public methods in the class, including those from superclasses. An alternative is [`Class.getDeclaredMethods()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods()), which returns all methods in that class *only*.

Comment: You guys are soo fast!..:P thanxs for the help!..the following code works perfectly!:

Class cl = Class.forName("Main");
for (Method method : cl.getMethods()){
   if(method.getName().equals("test")){
      Class[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
      method.invoke(null, "this is", " so cool!");
   }
}

Comment: (ehm could anybody help with the style ? ) (sorry)

Comment: Well i posted some code but the style isn't really good.. But never mind. I will post better code when it is finished (for people who might have the same problem).

Comment: I dont think people can edit comments. But have a look at the following link for future reference (or just click the help link next to the comment). http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24794/167981

Answer (score 5):

You can loop over all methods of a class using:

```
cls.getMethods(); // gets all public methods (from the whole class hierarchy)
```

or

```
cls.getDeclaredMethods(); // get all methods declared by this class
```

.

```
for (Method method : cls.getMethods()) {
    // make your checks and calls here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getMethods()` which returns an array of all methods of a class. 
Inside the loop you can inspect the parameters of each method.

```
for(Method m : cl.getMethods()) {
   Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
   ...
}
```

Otherwise you can use `getDelcaredMethods()` which will allow you to "see" private methods (but not inherited methods). Note that if you want to invoke a private methods you must first  apply [setAccessible(boolean flag)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject[],%20boolean%29) on it:

```
for(Method m : cl.getDelcaredMethods()) {
   m.setAccessible(true);
   Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok thanxs to all the people who answered my question here the final solution:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      String func = "test";
      Object arguments[] = {"this is ", "really cool"};
      try{
         Class cl = Class.forName("Main");
         for (Method method : cl.getMethods()){
            if(method.getName().equals(func)){
               method.invoke(null, arguments);
            }
          }
       } catch (Exception ioe){
          System.out.println(ioe);
       }
    }
  public static void test(String s, String b){
     System.out.println(s+b);
  }
}
```

Comment: A problem with this code is that it is not robust.  Various changes to the signature of `test` will result in exceptions; e.g. if the method is not `static`, if the number of args is different, it the types of the args are different, if the method is not visible.

Comment: yes that is right.. but there is no other way to do this. I need to be able to call functions from a string (this is because I need to be able to setup a socket connection to a java program and then send  json that will have the appropriate method name and arguments.) 
If i take care of my exception handling and have good unittests I think it will be robust enough (or i hope so :P ).