# List functions as selections in Java

Tags: java

I am a Java newbie so my questions may look like an easy one. But I need some direction from your guys.

Here is my question: I have a class with bunch of methods, I would like to give these methods to user in a combox to select, based on their selection some code will run. Now I can do this by writing switch selection method. Where based on selection I use switch to run a particular method.

But my list of functions is pretty long close to 200, SO my questions to you is: is there a smarter way of doing this. 
Just point me to the right direction and I'll try to do the rest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), specifically:  [`Class.getMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) or [`Class.getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29).

Make sure you understand the differences between them (read the linked javadocs for this), if you don't - don't be afraid to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I think looking into Java Reflection would be the best place to start, assuming I've understood what you want to do correctly.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Reflection for both listing the methods and calling them

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

[Using Java reflection to create eval() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621251/java-reflection)

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection (you can find a lot of information on Google) but it is not a good practice to simple show your methods to the user. In a more complex application you should try to separate presentation and true execution of what user want

Answer (score 0):

Each selection could be represented by an Enum which is built as a set of function pointers:

```
public enum FunctionPointer {
F1 {
    public SomeObject doFunction(args) {
        YourClass.doMethod(args);
    }
},
//More enum values here...
}
```

The syntax will need a little work, but in the client you can just call

```
FunctionPointer.F1.doFunction("abc");
```

Comment: it really isn't that disimilar to your switch statement, but I dislike reflection for things that can be done without it.