# Calling method from a component by its name in a string

Tags: java, string, methods

I just want to know if there is any way to call a method from on an object by its name in a String.

Something like this

`setLocation(int,int)` it's a method from `jLabel1`, how can i call this
`method(setLocation())` by using its name in string ?

```
String component = jLabel1.getName();
component.setLocation(x,y);
```

Comment: You would need to use Reflection. But what is the requirement, where you need to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the [Java reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621251/java-reflection) may helps you.

Comment: hm i will read the Reflection API thanks