# Java: Load class method based on string

Tags: java

I have seen a lot of stuff here about reflection to load a class and such, I just do not think that this is what I am looking for.
Basically, what I want is a way to load a method from a class dynamically.
So like: loadDynamicClass("NameFromString").onStart(); where onStart() is a method in each of the classes I am trying to load. If there is something on stackoverflow I missed, just mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the question is. You want to choose a class at runtime based on a string?

Comment: Pretty much, and then use a method from it.

Comment: Class.forName, then newInstance and then cast to some general type that has that method on it

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621251/java-reflection) which illustrates method invocation by name using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void bar()
    {
        System.out.println("Foo.bar");
    }

    public void car()
    {
        System.out.println("Foo.car");
    }
}
```

and code like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv) 
        throws ClassNotFoundException, 
               NoSuchMethodException, 
               InstantiationException, 
               IllegalAccessException,
               IllegalArgumentException,
               InvocationTargetException 
    {
        final Class<?> clazz;
        final Method   method;
        final Object   instance;

        clazz = Class.forName(argv[0]);
        method = clazz.getMethod(argv[1] /*, types */);
        instance = clazz.newInstance();
        method.invoke(instance /*, arguments */);
    }
}
```

You can run like this:

```
java Main Foo bar
java Main Foo car
```

and it will call the foo or bar method as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can load a class with the `Class.forName` method.

E.g.

```
(Cast) Class.forName("fully.qualified.class.Name").newInstance().yourMethod()
```

(Cast) - can be of a type that yourMethod()

Comment: Don't forget to cast.  Object does not contain youMethod :)